# Output of parametrized value as table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code, the idea being that the 'Tariff Lookup' value from the `[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]` table will be used as the `@tablevalue` in the second SQL query.

The trouble is the SQL string and not the output is being used.

Please could somebody help with the correct syntax so that the actual table name is used.

```
DECLARE @tablevalue nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @tablevalue = 'Select [Tariff Lookup] from [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]'

SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] 
SET    [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Sell Price] = [test].[dbo].' + @tablevalue +'.[Peak]/60*[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Duration (secs)]
FROM   [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014]
INNER JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[ChargeCode] = [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014].[Chargecode]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
PRINT @tablevalue
```

Also can I do it like this or do I need to parse each line one at a time.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
DECLARE @tablevalue nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @tablevalue  = [Tariff Lookup]
FROM [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls];

SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] 
SET    [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Sell Price] = [test].[dbo].' + @tablevalue +'.[Peak]/60*[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Duration (secs)]
FROM   [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014]
INNER JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[ChargeCode] = [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014].[Chargecode]';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
PRINT @tablevalue;
```

Comment: Yes, kind of - but I need to return a unique @tablevalue for each row if that makes sense. The [Tariff Lookup] column will vary per each row in the table and I am trying to do the update query using the appropriate Tariff for each customer

Comment: @user3580480 . . . I think that is a very different question from the one you asked.  I would suggest that you ask another question, including sample data and desired results.  I would ask you, though, why you have separate tariff tables instead of one table with all the appropriate information for tariffs.